# Marker 'position' not assignable to map.marker in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-maps

I am attempting to add info windows to my google map markers. However, when trying to assign position to my addMarker function I receive the error: 'Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'position' does not exist in type 'Marker'.'

Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

I'm following this "tutorial" : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

I have tried changing the marker from a marker to markerOptions which allowed me to add a position to the marker but subsequently disallowed the use of infoWindows.

I expect I have made a logical error somewhere and am blind from looking at the code too long.

```
export class GMapComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnChanges {
  
  constructor() { }

  @Input() userdata:any = {}
  @Input() pages:any = null
  index = 0
 
  map: google.maps.Map;
  markers: google.maps.Marker[] = [];

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  display : any;
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = {lat: -33.779104947067, lng: 25.558868084657444};
  zoom = 8;
 
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
      console.log(this.userdata)
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      console.log(changes)
      console.log(this.userdata.pages)

      let pagesWithGis = this.userdata.pages.filter(page => {
        return page.gis != null;
      });

      console.log(pagesWithGis)

      for(let i = 0; i < pagesWithGis.length; i++){

        let pageName = pagesWithGis[i].pageName;
        let type = pagesWithGis[i].gis.type;
        let longitude = pagesWithGis[i].gis.longitude;
        let latitude = pagesWithGis[i].gis.latitude;

        this.addMarker({
          position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, 
          title: pageName,
        });

        const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: `Page: ${pageName} - Type: ${type}`  
        });

        }

  }

  addMarker(marker: google.maps.Marker) {
    this.markers.push(marker);
    console.log(this.markers)
    console.log(marker)
  } 

  openInfoWindow(marker: google.maps.Marker, index: number) {
  this.infoWindow.open({
    anchor: marker,
  })
  }
```

}

Comment: Hello! I can see that you are using something like `markers: google.maps.Marker[] = [];` can you please show me a documentation that shows that this is used when loading a Marker? I'm not sure if this is right way of initializing a Marker array.

Comment: The "tutorial" you even linked is for pure Javascript and not in Angular. Can you please confirm if your using some Angular components for your implementation?